# Unable to grab some fields from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch the titles and the links of different container from this [webpage](https://www.firmy.cz/kraj-praha?q=prodej+kol) using `requests` module, but I can't find any way to do that. I tried to find any hidden API usually shows up in dev tools, but I failed. I've noticed different times that the content which generate dynamically most of the times are available in some script tag. However, in this case I could not find the content in there either. As a last resort I made use of Selenium to grab them.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = 'https://www.firmy.cz/kraj-praha?q=prodej+kol'

def get_content(url):
    driver.get(url)
    for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.companyDetail'))):
        item_link = item.find_element_by_css_selector("h3 > a.companyTitle").get_attribute("href")
        item_title = item.find_element_by_css_selector("span.title").text
        yield item_link,item_title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        for item in get_content(link):
            print(item)
```

The result the script produces are like:

```
('https://www.firmy.cz/detail/12824790-bike-gallery-s-r-o-praha-vokovice.html', 'Bike Gallery s.r.o.')
('https://www.firmy.cz/detail/13162651-bikeprodejna-cz-praha-dolni-chabry.html', 'BIKEPRODEJNA.CZ')
('https://www.firmy.cz/detail/406369-bikestore-cz-praha-podoli.html', 'Bikestore.cz')
('https://www.firmy.cz/detail/12764331-shopbike-cz-praha-ujezd-nad-lesy.html', 'Shopbike.cz')
```

***How can I grab the same result using requests module?***

Comment: Payload is being sent using `application/x-base64-frpc` content-type. I don't know if it possible to parse this content using requests library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having analysed the original page source the solution appears to be very simple - you have to append an additional `_escaped_fragment_=` URL param to your link. For example, a simple Python script to get the required content can be as follows:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.firmy.cz/kraj-praha?q=prodej+kol&_escaped_fragment_=')
print (r.content)
```

The below Python script mimics your current implementation using `requests` and parsing the received response:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base = 'https://www.firmy.cz'
link = 'https://www.firmy.cz/kraj-praha?q=prodej+kol&_escaped_fragment_='

def get_info(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".companyDetail"):
        item_link = urljoin(base,item.select_one("h3 > a.companyTitle")['href'])
        item_title = item.select_one("span.title").get_text(strip=True)
        yield item_link,item_title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in get_info(link):
        print(item)
```

Prior to executing, make sure that you have installed the required libraries by running the following commands in `cmd`:

```
pip install bs4
pip install html5lib
pip install lxml
```

Comment: This is something I was after. Now, the question is, where did you find the link? Thanks for your solution @Kate Orlova.

Comment: You are welcome, @SMTH. The link is defined in the meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/kraj-praha?q=prodej+kol&_escaped_fragment_=" />`

Comment: @SMTH, could you please accept my answer if you are happy? Thanks.